# Testing unsupervised KMeans

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm using the [sklearn tutorials](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_clustering.html#example-text-document-clustering-py) on text clustering to find any interesting grouping on reviews of beers.  So far it has been working out fine for me, however when it comes to testing, or finding the right parameters I've tried looping through different cluster numbers:

```
for clusters in range(3, 10):
    km = KMeans(n_clusters = clusters, init="k-means++", max_iter=100, n_init=1)
    km.fit(vectorizer_fit)
    order_centroids = km.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
    for i in range(clusters):
        print("Cluster %d:" %i, end="")
        for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
            print(" %s"%terms[ind],end=",")
        print()
```

it helps weed out some obvious choices (clusters 6+) start getting weird, or containing the beer's name:

```
Cluster 1: julius, th, treehouse, ego, alter, papaya, dipa, melon, canned, dankness
Cluster 7: citra, farmstead, dipa, hf, apa, passion, abner, nelson, mosaic, papaya
```

And then tried using diffrent max/min_df:

```
for x in range(40):
    tfidf_vector = TfidfVectorizer(max_df = (.8-(x * .01)), min_df = .2, \
                                    stop_words = "english", use_idf = True)
    tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vector.fit_transform(documents)
    km = KMeans(5)
    km.fit(tfidf_matrix)
    order_centroids = km.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]

    print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    print("With max_df @ %d% " % ()(.80 - (x*.01))*100))
    for i in range(5):
        print("cluster %d words: " % i, end = "") 
        for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:               #top N number of words
            print("%s "% vocab.ix[ind].values, end = ",") #lookup centroid number as vocab index
    print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
```

which helped find good points to eliminate most some stop words:

```
With max_df @ 80%: ['the'] ,['here'] ,['a'] ,['true'] ,['roasted'] ,['imparted'] ,['some'] ,['through'] ,['beer'] ,['such']
With max_df @ 60%: ['do'] ,['coffee'] ,['is'] ,['alcohol'] ,['retention'] ,['dry'] ['with'] ,['regular'] ,['little'] ,['speedway']
```

And I could hypothetically try looping through both at the same time, but at some point reading it and making a human judgement on the best doesn't seem the...computer scientist way.  Is there any way to evaluate unsupervised methods, without an exact business question in mind?

Comment: The problem is that k-means doesn't work very well at all on text, in my opinion. It is not robust to outliers, and text data is full of outliers. Word lists always look good to humans, because we are pretty good in attempting to make "sense" even from gibberish... See also: "Reading tea leaves: How humans interpret topic models"

Comment: I just got some free time and read that paper, and I now better understand there is a lack of quantitative metrics for qualitative mining tasks.  However the article just left me feeling that LDA is the best of the evils, instead of proposing a solution.  Did I fail to take something else away?

Comment: The other takeaway should probably be that this is hard, and may simply not work at all (yet appear 'okay' when looking at the top words)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'm trying to find some interesting projects to build into a resume so i'll be sure to incorporate these points into my conclusion paper.  Off to learn LDA!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the code but you could take a look at this archive paper : https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.05667 and its references

and Demo code for dbscan algorithm on sklearn https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html

I came across these while looking for unsupervised clustering evaluation metrics

edit: this post is also useful - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79028/performance-metrics-to-evaluate-unsupervised-learning